# Selecting First Row/Instance Where a Field Updated from NULL to a Value

Tags: t-sql

| RowNum | CreateDT | ID | OrderID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-04 12:01:54.000 | 55 | NULL |
| 2 | 2022-03-04 12:05:11.000 | 55 | 12700 |
| 1 | 2023-01-20 03:44:07.000 | 698 | NULL |
| 2 | 2023-01-24 17:51:35.000 | 698 | 24525 |
| 3 | 2023-01-25 20:00:43.000 | 698 | 24525 |
| 1 | 2023-02-13 09:12:01.000 | 1001 | NULL |
| 2 | 2023-02-13 10:27:58.000 | 1001 | NULL |
| 3 | 2023-02-17 22:09:22.000 | 1001 | 26831 |

Have the following data. How would I select the first instance/row where the OrderID went from NULL to a value, per ID?

Eg of What I would expect to see:
[image]

Comment: I tried the following and it worked, but wondering if there is a more efficient or replicable way with less room for error:

`WITH CTE AS (
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Partition BY ID ORDER BY RowNum, CreateDT) AS Row_Num, RowNum, CreateDT, ID FROM MyTable WHERE OrderID IS NOT NULL
)
SELECT RowNum, CreateDT, ID FROM CTE WHERE Row_Num = 1 ORDER BY ID`

I also know that the first rownum will always be NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should be to handle this using exists logic:

```sql
SELECT RowNum, CreateDT, ID
FROM yourTable t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM yourTable t2
    WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND
          t2.CreateDT < t1.CreateDT AND
          t2.OrderID IS NOT NULL
) AND
      OrderID IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY ID;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo